# Partitions have become inaccessible

Tags: efi, partition-recovery, boot-partition, dualboot

**SETUP**

Dell Chromebook 13 7310 (with [MrChromebox Firmware](https://mrchromebox.tech/))

EFI dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.10

**WHAT HAPPENED BEFORE THE PROBLEM EMERGED**

When my laptop cannot wake up from hibernation despite having tried to close and open the lid several times, I sometimes open it up and unplug the battery. This is something I have done multiple times over the 3+ years I have had the laptop and never had a problem with it.

Today I did it again, and after restarting the laptop I was able to boot into Ubuntu. I then closed the lid, turned the laptop around and placed the screws back on the back-cover.

As I re-opened the laptop, there was a black screen. So I turned the laptop off and after re-starting I noticed the option to boot into Ubuntu was not there.

To be precise I normally have four options...

- Windows
- EFI Internal Hard drive (which I use to boot into grub and then ubuntu)
- Ubuntu (which also brought me back to the boot menu so I never use it)
- EFI Internal shell

... but this time only three were available

- Windows
- Ubuntu
- EFI Internal shell

Only EFI Internal shell works, while the other two bring me back to the boot menu.

**WHAT I TRIED SO FAR**

Thinking that the problem was grub, I booted into a live-USB version of Ubuntu. However, I realized that I could not see my sda drive: rather the usb -drive appears as sda and the are no other drives.

I tried both with `gparted` and the command `sudo fdisk -l`, and neither can see it. I also tried `testdisk`, but these are the partitions I get:

```
Disk /dev/sda - 31 GB / 28 GiB - Kingston DataTraveler 3.0
Disk /dev/loop0 - 2027 MB / 1933 MiB (RO)
Disk /dev/loop1 - 93 MB / 89 MiB (RO)
Disk /dev/loop10 - 93 MB / 89 MiB (RO)
Disk /dev/loop11 - 3821 KB / 3732 KiB (RO)
Disk /dev/loop12 - 15 MB / 14 MiB (RO)
Disk /dev/loop13 - 978 KB / 956 KiB (RO)
Disk /dev/loop14 - 4403 KB / 4300 KiB (RO)
Disk /dev/loop15 - 46 MB / 44 MiB (RO)
Disk /dev/loop16 - 164 MB / 156 MiB (RO)
Disk /dev/loop2 - 56 MB / 53 MiB (RO)
Disk /dev/loop3 - 158 MB / 151 MiB (RO)
Disk /dev/loop4 - 4218 KB / 4120 KiB (RO)
Disk /dev/loop5 - 15 MB / 14 MiB (RO)
Disk /dev/loop6 - 1032 KB / 1008 KiB (RO)
Disk /dev/loop7 - 3821 KB / 3732 KiB (RO)
Disk /dev/loop8 - 37 MB / 35 MiB (RO)
Disk /dev/loop9 - 57 MB / 54 MiB (RO)
```

I am seriously worried I 'fried' the hard drive, or anyways that I will need to reinstall everything from scratch. Is there something else I can try before doing that?

Comment: What do you get if you enter `ls fs0:` (don't forget the `:` ) into efi shell?  It may not be *fs**0*** - you can use `map` to show what filesystems and block devices the efi can see.

Comment: Take the drive out and check if it works in another computer. Also, you should have backups.